ValueError: Shapes (None, 8631) and (8631,) are incompatible when converting TF 1 code to TF 2
I have the following TensorFlow code that I tried to convert from TF 1.14 to TF 2.10.0. I mainly did this by replacing tf with tf.compat.v1:
target = tf.compat.v1.keras.utils.to_categorical(target_idx, 8631)
target_variable = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.variable(target, dtype=tf.float32)
source = tf.compat.v1.keras.utils.to_categorical(source_idx, 8631)
source_variable = tf.compat.v1.Variable(source, dtype=tf.float32)

init_new_vars_op = tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer([target_variable, source_variable])
sess.run(init_new_vars_op)

class_variable_t = target_variable
loss_func_t = tf.compat.v1.keras.metrics.categorical_crossentropy(model.output.op.inputs[0], class_variable_t) # causes error
get_grad_values_t = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.function([model.input], tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.gradients(loss_func_t, model.input))

...


The code is for generating an adversarial patch with the LaVAN method from here. The method call of categorical_crossentropy() seems to cause the following error:
  File "d:\...\attacks\laVAN.py", line 230, in <module>
    perturb_one(VGGModel(vggface.ARCHITECTURE_RESNET50), "D:/BA-Python-Code/VGGFace2/n842_0056_01.jpg", 151, 500, save_to_disk=True, image_domain=True)
  File "d:\...\attacks\laVAN.py", line 196, in perturb_one
    preprocessed_array = generate_adversarial_examples(vggmodel, img_path, epsilon, src_idx, tar_idx, iterations, image_domain)
  File "d:\...\attacks\laVAN.py", line 90, in generate_adversarial_examples
    loss_func_t = tf.compat.v1.keras.metrics.categorical_crossentropy(model.output.op.inputs[0], class_variable_t)
  File "D:\...\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu210\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "D:\...\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu210\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 1990, in categorical_crossentropy
    return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
  File "D:\...\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu210\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5529, in categorical_crossentropy
    target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
ValueError: Shapes (None, 8631) and (8631,) are incompatible

When I used TF 1.14 the code (without the .compat.v1.) was working just fine but now, with TF 2.10.0, it wont work.
Could you please tell me how to fix this?
In both cases I am using the GPU version of Tensorflow on Windows.
I know that in the TF 1.14 code the shapes were (?, 8631) and (8631,) and there it worked.
